# In "Maze Runner: The Death Cure" what happened to Newt?

Tags: the-maze-runner

Did they just leave him in the burning city?

What happened to him?

Comment: She mostly got eaten by an alien. Mostly. Wait, wrong Newt.

Comment: Wait, Newt became a famous Magical Zoologist right?

Answer (score 1):

At the end scene of The Death Cure, we do not see Newt’s body so I'm guessing (as Newt died) they left his body there, the main possibilities to what happens to his corpse would either be that it gets burned to ashes, or it gets exploded.